# Limit of a Riemann integrable exist for a function, then is Lebesgue integrable

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure, riemann-integration

I have the following proposition:

**Proposition:** Let $-\infty<a<b\leq\infty$ and $f:[a,b]\rightarrow[0,\infty]$ such that
$$\lim_{x\ \rightarrow\ b}R\int_{a}^{x}f(t)\ dt<\infty$$
Where "$R\int$" means integration in "Riemann sense". Then $f$ is Lebesgue integrable, i.e. $\int_{[a,b]}f\ d\mu<\infty$ where $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure, and
$$\lim_{x\ \rightarrow\ b}R\int_{a}^{x}f(t)\ dt = \int_{[a,b]}f\ d\mu$$

**Idea:** I'm thinking in consider two cases: First suppose $b<\infty$, here the result is a quite obvious because the interval $[a,b]$ would be compact in $\mathbb{R}$ and therefore both integrals are equal for all $x\in[a,b]$ thus for limit also works. But in the other case $b=\infty$, here the integral is improper and there are cases where Riemann improper integral exist but the Lebesgue integral doesn't. Any hint is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming $f$ is Riemann integrable on any finite interval $[a,x]$ where $x < b \leqslant +\infty$, the Riemann and Lebesgue integrals coincide, with

$$\int_a^x f(t) \, dt = \int_{[a,x]} f \, d\mu= \int_{[a,b]}f \chi_{[a,x]} \, d\mu$$

Since it is given that $f$ is nonnegative we can apply the monotone convergence theorem to obtain

$$\lim_{x \to b-}\int_a^x f(t) \, dt = \lim_{x \to b-}\int_{[a,b]}f \chi_{[a,x]}\, d\mu = \int_{[a,b]}f \, d\mu$$

Comment: Indeed the sequence of functions $f\chi_{[a,x]}$ is increasing and nonnegative taking $x\ \to\ b-$, so monotone convergence works perfectly. Thank you so much, @RRL !

Comment: @CrisPaint: You’re welcome.